# Generating report with optional params using jasperStudio and mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, jasper-reports

I'm trying to generate report using jasperStudio with optional param $P{p_site_id}
if param not equal 0 return just matching data else return all data

I make condition on $match as below the code doesn't give me error when running
I got exception :  fields not found

how I can solve this ? please

```
{
    runCommand:
    {
        "aggregate" : "device_inventories",
            "pipeline" : [
              { $group: { _id: { deviceStatusCode: "$deviceStatusCode" , siteId : "$siteId"}, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
                    {
                       $match: {
                            $expr: {
                                 $cond: [
                                     { $eq: [ {$ifNull: [ $P{p_site_id},0 ] } , 0 ] },
                                     {$eq:[true,true]},
                                     {$eq:["_id.siteId" , $P{p_site_id}]},
                                 ]
                           }
                      }
                   }
                { $lookup: { from: "device_statuses", localField: "_id.deviceStatusCode", foreignField: "deviceStatusCode", as: "statusInfo" } },
                { $lookup: { from: "sites", localField: "_id.siteId", foreignField: "siteId", as: "sitesInfo" } },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 0,
                        statusInfo: { $first: "$statusInfo.deviceStatus" },
                        sitesInfo: { $first: "$sitesInfo.siteName" },
                        count: 1
                    }
                }
            ],
}
}
```

Comment: Rather than `{$eq:["_id.siteId" , $P{p_site_id}]}` do you want `{$eq:["$_id.siteId" , $P{p_site_id}]}`?  Also, where you have `{$eq:[true,true]}`, this could just be `true`.

Comment: I want to get all record or "just" record where  siteId equal to params p_site_id, if I provide value for params get just records that matching param else get all

Comment: Without `$`, won't you just be comparing a constant string?

Comment: yes, I want to compare collection item with constant string

Comment: Seems unusual that `$P{p_site_id}` would be set to `"_id.siteId"`.

Comment: How can I pass optional param to mongo query in jasperStudio? any example please

Comment: Is your query compatible with the [Jaspersoft version](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jaspersoft-mongodb-query-language) you are using?

Comment: yes, because this query is working but if i delete $match or set all like this $match:{}

Comment: I searched a lot there is no answers.
So I make JDBC connection with mongo Atlas..sql solve problem 

Comment: Glad you got it working for you, but I do wish you had tried my suggestions in the `"$match"`.

Comment: I tryed it but also I didn't get any columns after read fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clear way to achieve that the best solution to generate report from mongoDB atlas with jasper Studio is to create JDBC connection as mentioned on mongoDB atlas documentation
[JDBC Connection mongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/data-federation/query/sql/drivers/jdbc/connect/)